# How can i Redirect a new URL while i defined a Route attribute on my controller MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a controller defined as

`[Route(somecontroller1/someaction1{someid}]`

And when I try to `Redirect` it to another view

`Redirect("somecontroller2/someaction2{someid}")`

my URL is

`somecontroller1/someaction1{someid}/somecontroller2/someaction2{someid}`

so my question is how can I redirect only to
`somecontroller2/someaction2{someid}`

you can see the code below;

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("someController1/someaction1/{someid}")]
public ActionResult CreateComment(Comment  comment, int someid)
{

*//do something*

 return Redirect("someController2/someAction2/" + someid);

}
```

Comment: Hi Partluka. Welcome to SO. Please provide your code in your question, otherwise its almost imposible to understand whats happening. THX

Comment: try `return RedirectToAction("someAction2", "someController2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you forgot the leading "/" in your redirect.
If you redirect without the "/" at the beginning, asp.net tries to redirect to the given URL inside the calling controller.

Add the leading "/" and the redirect is absolute:

```
return Redirect("/someController2/someAction2/" + someid);
```

Or you can redirect directly to your controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction2", "SomeController2", new{id = someid});
```

It's important to understand whats happening while ASP.NET tries to route the requests. There are several ways to change/define the routing. Here are some links you might check:

https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/routing-in-asp-net-mvc/

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/routing-in-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect to action method.

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction2", "SomeController2", new{id = someid});
```

This will redirect the page to the view of the desired action.